# how set run as administrator in Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey in c#?

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

In my application, I am trying to set my application as startup by adding registry entry using the following code:

```
RegistryKey startupapp = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
startupapp.SetValue("App", "\"" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "\"" +" -start");
```

also I force my program to run as an administrator using the following code:

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

but,it dont work.when i restart my system,it dont run automatically.

but when delete following code:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

my application run automatically after restart.

How fix it?

Comment: Did you get any error message? Can you share it? Is registry value exist?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski
no,there is not error.what do i check?

Comment: Check that required registry value was added to `Run` key

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski
Sorry,exactly what path should I check?
I'm confused.

Comment: The path which you are writing to `SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski
do it add in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206168/discussion-between-seyed-vahid-and-pavel-anikhouski).